# for looping an ajax get in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

So I'm building a twitter clone, and running in to issues.  Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong with this code :/

To start with, I dump firebase url snippets in to an array.  I then have that url builder set up with a for loop to make multiple urls and return them based on what was in the firebase array.  Like so:

```
 function urlMakerOther(target, key) {
    if (!key) {                  // does key exist? If the key doesn't exist (falsy), then return line 16. Else, return line 18.
        for (var i = 0; i <= firebases.length + 1; i++) {
            return "https://" + firebases[i] + baseUrl + target + "/.json";
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i <= firebases.length + 1; i++) {
            return "https://" + firebases[i] + baseUrl + target + "/" + key + "/.json";
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I have a master call for the xhr:

```
 function masterXhr(verb, url, data, callback_success, callback_error, extra) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(verb, url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            if (callback_success && typeof (callback_success) == "function") {
                callback_success(JSON.parse(this.response));
                console.log(this.response);
            }
        } else {
            if (callback_error && typeof (callback_error) == "function") {
                callback_error("MASTER XHR ERROR: " + this.response);
            }
        }
    };
    if (data) {                          // check on VERB type (GET or POST)
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    } else {
        request.send();
    }
}
```

The callbacks get defined further down in other various functions, but they aren't really the source of any errors.  Later on I have it set to fire off the get function:

```
 function getChirps() {
    masterXhr('GET', urlMakerOther("chirps"), null, showChirpContent, genericErrorCallback);
}
```

...which calls out showChirpContent which is what renders the information to the screen.  The problem is, it's not running a get on each of the firebases in the firebase array.  It will only get the information from whatever is in position 0 of the array.  The other elements in the array are for people attached to a friends list, and their firebase location is dumped in to that firebase array.

I set up a console.log for the contents of the array and the array is being filled out properly, so I guess at this point, I'm running in to a wall.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to get this to run a get on each of the firebase locations?

EDIT:

I've altered the code so that there are no returns, and the masterXhr is being called multiple times.  Here's the bit now:

> ```
> function urlMakerGetter(target, key) {
>     if (!key) {                  // does key exist? If the key doesn't exist (falsy), then return line 16. Else, return line 18.
>         for (var i = 0; i <= firebases.length + 1; i++) {
>             var fbUrl = "https://" + firebases[i] + baseUrl + target + "/.json";
>             masterXhr('GET', fbUrl, null, showChirpContent, genericErrorCallback);
>         }
>     } else {
>         for (var i = 0; i <= firebases.length + 1; i++) {
>             return "https://" + firebases[i] + baseUrl + target + "/" + key + "/.json";
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The masterXhr function hasn't been changed for this, and it is properly pulling the data and populating the fields now.  The only issue is that it is also throwing the following errors from the console:

> GET https://undefined.firebaseio.com/chirps/.json 403 (Forbidden)
>   scripts.js:59 {"-JjpLkTguWVhro2JUcWn":{"date":"2015-03-07T17:49:15.175Z","message":"resplendent-inferno-4140","subject":"resplendent-inferno-4140","username":"josh"}}
>   scripts.js:59 {"-JjpV2eF6AMR4fSsUmN1":{"date":"2015-03-07T18:29:51.485Z","message":"HIIIIIIIIIIIIII","subject":"What's up man","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpVID5WGbJRMyGbQoc":{"date":"2015-03-07T18:30:55.364Z","message":"chirpychirpchirp","subject":"chirp chirpedy chirp","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpVNZdQ4O1oXVcGKMw":{"date":"2015-03-07T18:31:17.216Z","message":"chirp chirpen","subject":"chirpedy","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpVZew75UbFwhPscCq":{"date":"2015-03-07T18:32:06.838Z","message":"CHIRPY CHIRP CHIRPEN CHIRP CHIRP","subject":"chirp chirp","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpcL_qu0YLmcroygz4":{"date":"2015-03-07T19:06:06.241Z","message":"this is only a test","subject":"test","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpdounXxqY4xGIO7kf":{"date":"2015-03-07T19:12:32.611Z","message":"chirpy chirp","subject":"testy test","username":"Andrew"},"-Jjpe4ywHp0_-r07tCS-":{"date":"2015-03-07T19:13:42.552Z","message":"test","subject":"test","username":"Andrew"},"-JjpppRksuTHZJTH1pHd":{"date":"2015-03-07T20:05:00.369Z","message":"chirpy test","subject":"test","username":"Andrew"},"-JjptkQU_VsMCsHcuQPA":{"date":"2015-03-07T20:22:08.465Z","message":"test","subject":"test","username":"Andrew"}}
>   scripts.js:70 GET https://undefined.firebaseio.com/chirps/.json 403 (Forbidden)

The json stuff in between is normal and expected, I have it set to log out what it receives so I can make sure it is getting what I want it to.  The undefined/forbidden spots are the concern, though they aren't doing anything to the end result - it'd be better if they weren't there.  Trying to figure out where that's coming from now.

Comment: What arrays are you talking about??? Using `return` in a `for` loop just exits the function as usual, instead of "*dump items in an array*".

Comment: Sorry messed up the last message, the array is being populated in a different function.  This is just to go through the array and get the stuff.

Comment: Your `getChirps` function only calls `masterXhr` once. Why would you expect it to retrieve multiple results? And I'm not sure what you think you're doing in the `urlMakeOther` function, but it's completely broken. If that's not an accurate representation of your code, please update or remove it.

Comment: I've since altered the code based on things I've read here and talked about with other people here in the building, it's doing a bit better now.  I'll update the code quick so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is only returning a single string not an array of strings. In order to return an array of strings you would need to add each string to an array and return the array e.g.

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= firebases.length + 1; i++) {
   var url = "https://" + firebases[i] + baseUrl + target + "/" + key + "/.json";
   array.push(url);
}
return array;
```

Comment: Is that because I'm using return?  If so, which command would be the better choice here?  I don't want the function to cease until i is properly less than the length of the array firebases[].

Comment: @abeth86: And what do you expect your function to return?

Comment: I'm hoping for it to return data from the firebase to be posted in to an html file.  It stringifys everything once it's been received, and then appends it to a table.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide an example of how to add items to an array and return the array. Hope that helps.